# Using 2 NSPredicates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to have 2 conditions met in my NSPredicate, but I am getting the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(whosEval == %@) AND ([age integerValue] >= 9 && [age integerValue] <= 11)"'
```

I know the issue is formatting, but I can't find any questions that help me. What am I doing incorrectly? This is the code I am using. NOTE: age is a string attribute of a core data entity.

```
        NSPredicate *evalPredicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(whosEval == %@) AND 
([age integerValue] >= 9 && [age integerValue] <= 11)", currentAthlete];
```

Comment: you cannot put things like integerValue into the predicate this will not work and is causing you the error you are seeing

Comment: @darren102: How would you suggest I check the age since it's an NSString?

Comment: would suggest using an NSNumber as the age attribute in Core Data otherwise you need to pull on the first predicate get the NSArray then do predicate with block in objective c to use the integerValue method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use the following:

```
NSPredicate *evalPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(whosEval == %@)", currentAthlete];
```

Run this in Core Data then assuming NSArray *results

results predicateWithBlock: to parse in objective c